# Strange 'null' string as value and makes the String object not empty, why?

Tags: java

Try this code, and you will see the output, the code uses two String one in a class and another in a variable, the output of the both usages is very different and strange, why and how can I solve it?

```
---------With class...
null
null
null hello
---------With variable...
null

 hello
```

Setting null to the name becomes into this value for the String, why? I need the name to be null and not 'null'.

Thanks by your help.

```
//'main' method must be in a class 'Rextester'.
//Compiler version 1.8.0_72

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Car {
   private String name;

   public void setName( String name ) { 
       if (this.validateName( name )) 
          this.name = name; 
   }

   public String getName() { return name; }

   public boolean validateName(String name) { 
      return name != null && name.trim() != ""; 
   }

   public boolean validate()
   { return this.validateName( this.name ); }
}

class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        System.out.println( "---------With class..." );
        Car t = new Car();

        t.setName(null);
        System.out.println( t.getName() );

        t.setName("");
        System.out.println( t.getName() );

        t.setName(t.getName() + " hello" );
        System.out.println( t.getName() );     

        System.out.println( "---------With variable..." );

        String nullString = new String();

        nullString = null;
        System.out.println( nullString );

        nullString = "";
        System.out.println( nullString );

        nullString = nullString + " hello";
        System.out.println( nullString );
    }
}
```

Comment: Though it doesn't directly answer the question, we have had servlets give the value 'null' (the String), so we added tests such that: ` if ("null".equals(test) || StringUtils.isBlank(test)) { ... }`. The Apache Commons is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the isEmpty() method which will return true if name is empty.

```
name.isEmpty()
```

Comment: However, whether the test is appropriate depends upon whether a String with N spaces is allowable. Depends upon the validation requirements. A username of "     " (all spaces) is probably a bad idea; it is not empty, but trimmed it will be. `name != null && name.trim().isEmpty()` is an option.

Comment: Can be thown an NPE is name is null

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `'validateName(String name)'` method returns `'false'` hence `'setName(String name)'` method doesn't do anything and the class member `'name'` remains `'null'`.

This originates from the fact that `'request.get parameter("name")'` call returns an empty string as per your post.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could just try to change you setName to :

```
   public void setName( String name ) { 
       if (this.validateName( name )) {
          this.name = name; 
       } else {
          this.name = "";
       }
   }
```

as an alternative? Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You output is from this statement:

```
System.out.println( "'" + name + "'" )
```

which just prints the result of a string concatenation with a null value in it.

According to [JLS 15.18.1 String Concatenation Operator `+`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1):

> If only one operand expression is of type `String`, then string conversion ([§5.1.11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11)) is performed on the other operand to produce a string at run time.

[JLS 5.1.11 String Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11)  says:

> If the reference is `null`, it is converted to the string "`null`" (four ASCII characters `n`, `u`, `l`, `l`).

If you want to print the text `null` without the quotes, then you have to not print quotes:

```
System.out.println( name != null ? "'" + name + "'" : "null" )
```

or if you want a null to print like an empty string (dumb, because then you cannot see the difference):

```
System.out.println( "'" + (name != null ? name.toString() : "") + "'" )
```

---

On a **different topic**, `name.trim() != ""` won't work.

You cannot use `==` and `!=` to compare strings.

Use `! name.trim().isEmpty()`.

---

**Third note:** You `setName()` should not silently ignore bad input.

```
public void setName( String name ) { 
    if (this.validateName( name )) 
        this.name = name; 
}
```

This code should either fail on bad input:

```
public void setName( String name ) { 
    if (! this.validateName( name ))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Name cannot be null or blank");
    this.name = name; 
}
```

Or assign null or blank on bad input:

```
public void setName( String name ) { 
    if (this.validateName( name )) 
        this.name = name; 
    else
        this.name = null; // or ""
}
```

Comment: Hi please look the new update of the question, and test the latest code and you will see the difference of using the String name with a variable and the class.

Comment: In the line `t.setName(t.getName() + " hello" )`, the value of `getName()` is null. In the line `nullString + " hello"`, the value of `nullString` is an empty string. That's why they act differently. See *third note* of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake in other answer.

I believe that [`StringUtils.defaultIfBlank`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#line.6309) from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) solve your problem.

In API you can see that:

> Returns either the passed in CharSequence, or if the CharSequence is whitespace, empty ("") or null, the value of defaultStr.

```
t.setName(StringUtil.defaultIfBlank(request.getParameter("name"), null));
```